# Can someone help me identify the error in the prime generator function I wrote

Tags: python, generator

Can someone help me why I get certain numbers like "27" and "35" in my generator when I'm listing out the first 25 primes? I know there are more efficient methods like the Sieve of Erathosthenes, but I'm concerned about some bug within this code. Thank you!

```
def next_prime():
    num = 2
    while True:
        for i in range(1, num+1):
            if (i != 1) and (num % i == 0):
                # print(num, " is not prime")
                num += 1
        yield num
        num += 1

primes = next_prime()
[print(next(primes)) for i in range(25)]
```

### Output below-- A few of the composite numbers are highlighted

3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
**27**
29
31
**35**
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
87

Answer (score 1):

You *increment* `num` in the `for` loop, but you can not simply do that, since then `i` is *not* reset to `1`, and hence you miss certain checks.

You thus should `break`, and then increment the `num` and let the loop check the  next number. We can thus use a `for`-`else` to only yield a number if the loop was successful (i.e. did not reach a `break` statement).

Another problem that now will occur is that *no* number is prime anymore. This is because your `range(1, num+1)` *includes* `num`, and a number is always dividable by itself. The range should thus span between `1` (or better `2`), and `num` (exclusive):

```
def next_prime():
    num = 2
    while True:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield num
        num += 1
```

The above is however *not* very efficient. We can make this way faster. For example all even numbers, except for two are not primes, we can thus rewrite this to:

```
def next_prime():
    yield 2
    num = 3
    while True:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if not num % i:
                break
        else:
            yield num
        num += 2
```

We furthermore only need to check up to √n for a number `n`, since if `n` is dividable by a number `a` with `a` greater than the square root of `n`, then there exists a number `b = n / a` that is smaller than the square root:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil

def next_prime():
    yield 2
    num = 3
    while True:
        for i in range(3, ceil(sqrt(num))+1, 2):
            if not num % i:
                break
        else:
            yield num
        num += 2
```